# Setup 404 status page with React Router + Hostinger's Litespeed Server

Tags: reactjs, litespeed

I have a React application hosted on Hostinger, which uses LiteSpeed as the web server. I am using React Router for routing, and I have a custom 404 page set up to render whenever a route doesn't match any defined routes. However, I noticed that even though the custom 404 page is rendered, the status code returned is always 200 or 304, which is causing issues with SEO.

Here is the file structure of my hostinger web server:

```
public_html /
  images /
  static /
  asset-manifest.json
  index.html
  robots.txt
```

Things I've Tried

---

.htacess:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Setting the status on a useEffect in my component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.status = "404" // or a 404 number
}, [])
```